# phpmyadmin - clicking a button does not work

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Buttons such as "browse" or "structure" are not working unless I open them in a new tab. This is for server- on my localhost it is working perfectly. I have tried restarting both the server and the MYSQL, but it hasn't fixed the issue. Any ideas?

I think this started after I accidentally checked the Profiling box. Now I can't uncheck it.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this with the current phpMyAdmin; could you tell us which version you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Although none of the buttons on the interface were working, by unchecking profiling and then clicking the refresh button (not the browser refresh) seemed to do the trick.